# Duplicado de error de validación personalizado en Djanngo

Tags: html, python, django

Realicé una validación personalizada dentro de mi formulario de creación de usuario donde solicito que el dominio sea específico. El error funciona bien, el problema es que en mi html se ve duplicado cuando lo renderizo no sé por qué.

Este es mi modelo:

class Usuario (AbstractUser):

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name='Grupos', related_name='Usuarios')
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    verbose_name='Permisos de usuario',
    blank=True,
    related_name='Usuarios'
)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Usuarios"

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

**Esta es la validación personalizada:**

```
def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not email.endswith('@gmail.com'):
            raise forms.ValidationError("El correo electrónico debe ser del dominio gmail.com.")
        return email
```

**Mi HTML en la parte de renderizar los errores del form:**

```
<form action="", method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{usuario_form.as_p}}
<button type="submit">Crear usuario</button>
<button type="submit">Ingresar</button>
{% if usuario_form.errors %}
 <div style="color: red;">
    {% for field, errors in usuario_form.errors.items %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <p>{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endif %}
```

**Y así es como se ve en el front duplicado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Muchas gracias por su ayuda.***